# Help understand ContentType/List upgrade

Tags: visual-studio, content-type, feature-upgrade, solution-deployment

Everywhere i read on the web it says that Content Types and List once deployed through Xml files they cannot be updated anymore.

I have created a VS 2010 solution, created a SharePoint List Definition with a Content type inline and deployed it. Everything works. Also added some items to my new list.

Now i edit the Schema.xml of the ListDefinition, i add a couple of fields, remove some, and change Type of others. Hit Deploy. Deploy succeeds. When i check the site, my content type fields have updated correctly and my list items previously entered are still there. So what's that about?

I saw that VS does a Retract/Add Solution/Activate, but if no data is lost and the content types update correctly, why use bother writing Feature receivers and upgrade code when i can simply "Retract/Add Solution/Activate"

Thanks